# Vscode attach debug output window

Tags: visual-studio-code

I do not want Vscode to open up another window while debugging. Is there a way to attach this window inside the IDE?

If the above is impossible, is there a way to choose a more usable terminal? The default terminal doesn't allow for text selection which makes it unacceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since VSCode is not an IDE, we do not have a built-in terminal.
I tried the terminals on OS X, Linux, and Windows. They all allow me to select and copy text (however on Windows it is through the 'Edit' > 'Mark' mechanism).

Andre Weinand, Visual Studio Code

Comment: it's not an IDE really ?

Comment: Quoted from https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode : "VS Code is a new type of tool that combines the simplicity of a code editor with what developers need for their core edit-build-debug cycle"

Answer (score 1):

The vscode forums have a request for an integrated terminal with a number of upvotes, i'd advise adding your voice to the chorus.

Answer (score 1):

It's a must to output the debug console writes to an attached panel in Visual Studio Code.  Click an highlight a word in the debug output console text to do a global project search to find all code containing that string.  A common thing like tagging error blocks with a  unique ID that gets output to the console when the error happens.  Full text search of the project source code tree for the ID...